# Webhook call failed. Error: 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: dialogflow-es-fulfillment

https://dialogflow.com/docs/tutorial-build-an-agent/create-fulfillment-using-webhook

I want to try this example out

but after I follow the step on this page

It's give me

Webhook call failed. Error: 500 Internal Server Error

```
{
  "responseId": "a89123c6-42e5-45fa-ab2d-153a9d7e3692",
  "queryResult": {
    "queryText": "I need to make an appointment at 3 PM today.",
    "parameters": {
      "time": "",
      "date": ""
    },
    "allRequiredParamsPresent": true,
    "fulfillmentMessages": [
      {
        "text": {
          "text": [
            ""
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "intent": {
      "name": "projects/newagent-b231a/agent/intents/f6477cf2-cd73-4dc3-a8bd-614d45998754",
      "displayName": "Make Appointment"
    },
    "intentDetectionConfidence": 1,
    "diagnosticInfo": {
      "webhook_latency_ms": 142
    },
    "languageCode": "zh-tw"
  },
  "webhookStatus": {
    "code": 13,
    "message": "Webhook call failed. Error: 500 Internal Server Error"
  }
}
```

amd I check logs on firebase
[image: firebase error log]

how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I faced the similar error. After I updated the npm. It was resolved.

try `npm install`